# React router v.6 revalidate loaders after submit form with formik

Tags: reactjs, react-router, formik, rtk-query

I have react-router v6 routes with loaders and actions (with rtk query requests) and I want to revalidate data (GET updated data after PUT) after submitting form that is handled with Formik.

I'm submitting form with useSubmit from react-router-dom. Data from form are in action, PUT is successfull but loader are not revalidated. I want to call GET from loader to get new updated data after PUT action. I also tried useRevalidator, but same as with useSubmit, after submit only PUT is called. Do you know how to revalidate loader after submit form with action?

```
                {
                  path: 'edit',
                  element: <HedrEdit />,
                  loader: args =>
                    baseLoader(
                      args,
                      enhancedHedrApi.endpoints.getHedrById,
                      'hedrId'
                    ),
                  action: async ({ request, params }) => {
                    const formData = await request.formData();
                    const values = Object.fromEntries(formData);
                    const data: PutHedrByIdApiArg = {
                      id: Number(params.hedrId),
                      hedr: values,
                    };
                    await editFetch(
                      enhancedHedrApi.endpoints.putHedrById,
                      data
                    );
                    return redirect(`/hedr/${params.hedrId}/edit`);
                  },
                },
```

```
const submit = useSubmit();

const formikState = useFormik<HedrModel>({
    initialValues: {
      name: data?.name|| '',
    },
    validateOnChange: false,
    validateOnBlur: false,
    enableReinitialize: true,

    onSubmit: (values)=> {
      const data: PutHedrByIdApiArg = {
        ...values,
      };
      submit(data, { method: 'put' });
    },
  });
```

```
      <Form
        onSubmit={formikState.handleSubmit}
        method="put"
        id="hedr-form"
      >
         <AdminInput
           type="text"
           autoComplete="off"
           required
           {...getFieldProps('name')}
         />
        <Button type="submit" buttonStyle="third">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Form>
```

Comment: What `Form` component are you using? The route [should revalidate](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/should-revalidate) automatically when an `action` is called from a `<Form>`. The code example is a bit incomplete so it's difficult to say what should or shouldn't work. All I can say is that if you are using all the RRDv6 Data APIs correctly, the loader revalidation should happen automatically.

Comment: Yes it should happen automatically, but it doesn't. I tried Form, useSubmit, useRevalidator and fetcher from RRDv6, but without success, action request is successful but without loader revalidation. Requests in actions and loaders are made with RTK Query, this can't be the problem?

Comment: Think you could create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: I finally figure it out, the problem was with RTK Query, after invalidate cache https://reactrouter.com/en/main/guides/data-libs#invalidating-data-in-mutations it working as expected. Thanks for help!

Comment: You know, I was going to go that route but thought I'd give you working with RTKQ and RRD route loaders the benefit of a doubt that it might actually work. Yeah, invalidating a query's tags will trigger an automatic refetch. This is outside anything RRD is doing though. So far I've not come up with any great way to use RTKQ and data loaders together, their use cases are just *too* misaligned. Glad it is working for you now. Cheers.